# Use VF functions with vue.js

Tags: visualforce

I am using vue.js inside a vf page but it is throwing me an error when I'm trying to save the following line.

```
                <apex:outputText value="{! UPPER( {{day.Month}} ) }"/>
```

How can I save this to work?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking to do isn't possible. In Visualforce, everything inside the merge field (`{! ... }`) is evaluated and rendered on the server, while everything in a Vue merge field (`{{ ... }}`) is rendered by the client. The client can't bind to anything inside the Visualforce merge field, because the Visualforce formula is never visible to the client.